# Flexible code to build a CSV-String in Swift 4.2

Tags: arrays, swift, csv

I have a small problem and don‘t know how to solve this.
I have got three (or more) Arrays and want to create a CSV-String with a universal function of them.

For example:

```
var firstname = ["Phil", "Kate", "Wendy", "Nick"]
var street = ["Groove Street", "Howard Street", "Highway 98", "Wall Street"]
var country = ["United Kingdom", "Australia", "Canada", "New Zealand"]
```

My goal is it to create a function in this type:

```
func csvCreator([“firstname“,“street“,“country“]) -> String {}
//the integration of the array is wrong
```

The output should be:

```
csvString = “firstname;street;country\nPhil;Groove Street;United Kingdom\nKate;Howard Street;Australia\nWendy;Highway 98;Canada\nNick;Wall Street;New Zealand
```

I want to keep my code flexible, so that I can simply add another category (for example an array of ages) by writing the function like this:

```
var age =  ["22", "21", "44", "16"]
func csvCreator([“firstname“,“street“,“country“,“age“]) -> String {}
//the integration of the array is wrong
```

The name of the variables should be asked in the function with an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in an array of your data arrays along with the array of column titles.

Here's a very rough start. Lots of details need to be added and fixed but this gives you a good start. Creating CSV is not as simple as most people think.

```
func csvCreator(titles: [String], data: [[String]]) -> String {
    // Add checks to ensure all arrays have the same length

    func buildRow(_ values: [String]) -> String {
        // This needs lots of work to deal with values that contain ; or newline characters
        return values.joined(separator: ";") + "\n"
    }

    var result = buildRow(titles)
    for row in data {
        result += buildRow(row)
    }

    return result
}
```

Then you might call it like:

```
var firstname = ["Phil", "Kate", "Wendy", "Nick"]
var street = ["Groove Street", "Howard Street", "Highway 98", "Wall Street"]
var country = ["United Kingdom", "Australia", "Canada", "New Zealand"]
let csv = csvCreator(titles: ["firstname","street","country"], data: [firstname, street, country])
```